# Script block if and variable

Tags: powershell

my path var which right now I set directly is:

```
00257d48e8260671794a3c2cfc3fb2d1  My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-11-13 10-57-52.mov
20e2128b66ded28cc59eb764209ddacd  My Pictures/Mom/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-11-12 09-26-27.dng
44e2128b66de428cc59eb764209ddacd  My Pictures/Mom/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2024-11-12 09-26-27.dng
```

in my code this is getting set further up in a foreach loop `foreach ($path in $diffmd5.value) {}`

heres the get type

```
$path.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ScriptBlock                              System.Object
```

seems like there's an issue using the variable inside the if ?

```
if ($path | Select-String  -Pattern 'My Pictures\/Mom\/') {
>>  $path2 = Split-Path -Path $path -Leaf }
Split-Path : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Path' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no
input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At line:2 char:28
+  $path2 = Split-Path -Path $path -Leaf }
+                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCommand
```

some issue here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters

Comment: What is the type of `$path`? Is it a string or an array?

Comment: its a string obj.

Comment: How are you generating that value for `$path`? Is it a collection of strings? Using `Split-Path` will result in a collection of names and not just one path. Are you able to cast a type of `[string[]]` to it?

Comment: right now its just a var that I set directly

Comment: ""*right now its just a var that I set directly*" add that also to the question. (I guess that you using curly brackets, which you shouldn't as there isn't hardly any cmdlet/function/method that produces a scriptblock ether).

Comment: What is the code that sets $path?

Comment: Why would `$path` be set as a scriptblock that doesnt make any sense

Comment: its in a foreach loop - added detail to the OP

Comment: "*its in a foreach loop&", that doesn't make any sense either, please show us ([in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74447123/edit)) what you doing here.

Comment: What code sets $diffmd5.value?